# Plugin migration question

Tags: plugin-development, database, migration

Reposted from Slack

I have tried to create a migration using console (as per docs) but whilst it created a `migrations` folder it did not create a migration file. So resorted to creating manually but now getting the following error:

```
Status: Internal Server Error
Response: <h1>Craft\Exception</h1> <p>Could not validate update handle.
```

The offending migration file can be viewed at https://gist.github.com/cole007/4bfff23c693ca496ca4929f464df2a05

Looking into the Update Controller that is throwing the error it seems to be down to the `_getFixedHandle()` method where $data['handle'] is returning empty but no idea why this is.

Any thoughts on debugging or resolving? Site launch is imminent so need to get to the bottom of why this is happening soon!

Thanks,

Cole

Answer (score 2):

Okay - this was a problem at our end. 
We had a plugin which provided a twig extension that modified Craft's own hash method which was causing issues with the migration update.

Consider solved!